# Contentcontrol or dockpanel for navigation wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, contentcontrol, dockpanel

I use a Contentcontrol to show the user controls of the program, Now there is a problem for me to close the user controls After searching, I found an example that The user controls is loaded on a DockPanel
Now my questions:

1. What is the difference between these two controls? (Dockpanel vs ContentControl)
2. Is it okay to use this control(dockpanel) Instead of Contentcontrol to display application user controls?
3. Is there a similar code for Contentcontrol?

   ```
   ucChild ChildWindow = new ucChild();  
   ChildWindow.ParentControl = this.UIPanel;  
   UIPanel.Children.Clear();  
   UIPanel.Children.Add(ChildWindow);
   ```

Comment: it is simpler to name what DockPanel and ContentControl have in common, because they are very different. Did you try to read Microsoft documentation? MS provides *excellent* documentation for .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Standard disclaimer for people coding WPF like it is WinForms:** First off; direct UI manipulation like this is a bad idea. You should
>   be modifying a view model and allowing the binding system to update
>   the UI. Use the MVVM pattern; WPF will work *for* you instead of
>   against you

To your actual questions:

1. Everything. I mean; they both inherit from `FrameworkElement` but that's about it in terms of commonality.

   - A `DockPanel` is as the name suggests, a `Panel`. That is; it controls the layout and sizing of one or more child elements. Specifically, `DockPanel` is good at situations like the following: you want an element to use up a full column of width, then another span the top (except for the previous element) and have the last element fill the remaining space.
   - A `ContentControl` is basically a placeholder, its purpose is to expose a settable (and most importantly, bindable) `Content` property that you can stuff another control into. Even better; you can put an actual *object* there and use a `DataTemplate` to control the display (this approach would conform to MVVM).
2. You can't really replace one with the other, see above
3. No. `ContentControl` is not a `Panel` and so does not have the `Children` property.